# When I using Qt Creater 5 to debug QML,it doesn't work.But it runs well using qmlscene

Tags: qt, qml

There is no error about my codes.

> **Starting D:\qtworkspace\test\cnm\build-cnm-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\cnm.exe...**
>   QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

It doesn't have exit code 0.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    //app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/LOGO.ico"));
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:clientWindow
    width: 1820
    height: 980
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    //flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    //       | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
    //       | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
    //       | Qt.Window
}
```

Comment: Please add some code of yours.

Comment: #include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    //app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/LOGO.ico"));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

Comment: import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:clientWindow;
    width: 1820;
    height: 980;
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2;
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2;
    //flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint| Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint| Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint| Qt.Window;
 }

Comment: I meant, you should edit your question, so that it includes the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to write *good questions*, that then will hopefully receive a *good answer*. When that happens, [**follow this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also take a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to find out, how you can format your questions and answers in a nice and readable way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a very small but a common one, as the problem is a little bit hidden in the documentation.

Your program indeed works, and the `ApplicationWindow` is created. You can check for this, by adding `Component.onCompleted: console.log('created')` to your `ApplicationWindow`.

The problem is with the `visibility` of the `Window`. This is controlled with [`visibility: Window.VisiblityEnum`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#Visibility-enum). By default this property is set to `0` which indicates `Window.Hidden`.
This sets `visible: false`. So - while being created your `Window` is not shown.

You can also control the visibility of your `Window` with the `visible`-property. Setting it to `false` is equal to setting `visibility: Window.Hidden` and setting it to `true` is equal to `visibility: Qt.AutomaticVisiblity` if nothing else was set before.

`qmlscene` is using different defaults for this.

---

Concluding, you can either use this code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:clientWindow
    width: 1820
    height: 980
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    //flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    //       | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
    //       | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
    //       | Qt.Window
    visibility: Window.AutomaticVisibility
}
```

or

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:clientWindow
    width: 1820
    height: 980
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    //flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    //       | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
    //       | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
    //       | Qt.Window
    visible: true
}
```